# How can I get a string from user without spaces using scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

This is a C code to get a string for types of brackets '()' & '<>' & '{}' & '[]' from user. The length of this string is n and it is an user input.

```
int main()
{
  long int n;
  int i;
  scanf("%lld", &n);
  char array[n];
  for(i=0; i<n ; i++)
  {
     scanf("%s", &array[i]);
  }
 }
```

The problem is I want to get the string without any spaces between them from user. But, this code is working for the input with space between each character and give the correct result.

For example, if I type `{(()` the program won't run. but if I type `{ ( ( )` the program shows the correct result. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: change     `scanf("%s", &array[i]);` to      `scanf("%c", &array[i]);`

Comment: I have tried it. The output changes and becomes wrong. But the problem of spaces becomes solved this way.

Comment: That is because `\n` is left behind. To consume new line add space before `%c`. Like this `scanf(" %c", &array[i]);`

Comment: @Andromeda nice question, with a complete minimal example! Make sure to read my updated answer, for null terminating your strings! Hope that helps Ανδρομέδα!

Comment: @gsamaras I've read it. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: `long int n; ... scanf("%lld", &n);` is UB.  Use matching specifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
scanf("%s", &array[i]);
```

to this:

```
scanf(" %c", &array[i]);
```

since what you attempt to do is read your string character by character.

Please notice the space before `%c`, which will consume the trailing newline that is going to be left in the stdin buffer from when you entered `n`.

I had wrote about the caution when reading a character with `scanf()` [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/).

Now, even if you use `{(()` or `{ ( ( )` for the input, it will be the same, since `scanf()` will ignore the whitespaces.

However, you should *null terminate* your string, if you want it to be used by standard functions, which you almost certainly want. For example, if you were to use `printf("%s", array);`, then you must have `array` null terminated.

An approach to this, assuming that the user will input correctly (in a perfect world), you could do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  long int n;
  int i;
  scanf("%ld", &n);

  // create an extra cell to store the null terminating character
  char array[n + 1];

  // read the 'n' characters of the user
  for(i=0; i<n ; i++)
  {
     scanf(" %c", &array[i]);
  }

  // null terminate the string
  array[n] = '\0';

  // now all standard functions can be used by your string
  printf("%s\n", array);

  return 0;
 }
```

---

PS: `scanf("%lld", &n);` --> `scanf("%ld", &n);`. Use your compiler's warnings! It will tell you about it..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the user types at least 1 space character between each 'valid' character, you can just wait in the loop until the user adds a space character.

```
    char c;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        c = '\0';
        while (c != ' ')        // wait for the user to type a space character
        {
            scanf ("%s", &c);
        }
        while (c == ' ')        // wait for the user to type something else
        {
            scanf ("%s", &c);
        }
        array[i] = c;
    }
```